# Update table field from a different table with if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as;

Table 1

```
[SKU], [QTY_on_hand]
```

Table 2

```
[XREF] , [QTY_on_hand]
```

I want to update Table 2 's [QTY_on_hand] with Table 1 's [QTY_on_hand]
where [SKU]=[XREF] and if Table1's [QTY_on_hand] is greater than "30" else table2 's [QTY_on_hand] = '0'.

So the T-SQL is:

```
update Table 2
set [QTY_on_hand] = t.[QTY_on_hand]
from Table 1 t
where t.[SKU] = [XREF]
```

But the if statement is missing here and I couldn't manage to how to integrate if statement with 'case when' or 'if-else'.

Comment: Please include data sample and the desired result in your question.

Comment: Also please sync table names between your code and description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follows is how to join a second table to the table being updated in an update statement and use a conditional expression for updating a value:

```
update T2 set
  qty_on_hand = case when T1.qty_on_hand > 30 then T1.qty_on_hand else 0 end
from Table2 T2
inner join Table1 T1 on T1.SKU = T2.XREF
where ?? -- surely you don't want to update the entire table?
```

Comment: if the T1.SKU needs to update multiple corresponding XREF fields on T2 would this SQL work?

Comment: @MYB The `update` statement allows multiple columns to be updated (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in one go - is that what you mean?

Comment: For ex. if there are 3 rows of "a" in the XREF field in T2. would SKU 'a' qty_on_hand in T1 update that 3 rows at the same time?

Comment: Well yes, the join condition is only `T1.SKU = T2.XREF` so every record that matches will be updated - thats how SQL works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. XREF fields had some extra blanks which correspond with T1.SKU so I trimmed it. Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a case expression like this

```
UPDATE Table2
    SET Qty_on_Hand = CASE WHEN SKU=XREF AND Qty_on_Hand > 30 THEN Table1.Qty_on_Hand ELSE Table2.Qty_on_Hand END
```